# Implementation issue in deleting the node of a binary search tree in c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have implemented delete method for a Binary Search Tree by referring the pseudo code from CLRS. Below is the buggy implementation. Initially when I delete the leaf node it works but when I am deleting the root node the code fails. Specifically - Value of new root node is coming in the transplant method but in the delete_node method it again shows old node value.
Could someone please point out the error. Thanks in advance.

```
class bst {
    public:
        struct node
        { 
            int data;
            struct node* ltson;
            struct node* rtson;
            struct node* parent;
        }*btroot;

        // replaces the subtree rooted at node u with the subtree rooted at node v

        void transplant(bst T, struct node* u, struct node *v) {
            if(u->parent==NULL){
                T.btroot = v;
            }
            else if(u->parent->ltson == u)
                u->parent->ltson = v;
            else 
                u->parent->rtson = v;
            if(v!=NULL)
                v->parent = u->parent;
        }

        void delete_node(bst T,struct node* z) {
            struct node * y;

            if(z->ltson==NULL)
                transplant(T,z,z->rtson);
            else if(z->rtson==NULL)
                transplant(T,z,z->ltson);
            else {
                y = minimum(z->rtson); 

                if(y->parent!=z) {
                    transplant(T,y,y->rtson);
                    y->rtson = z->rtson;
                    y->rtson->parent = y;
                }
                transplant(T,z,y);
                cout<< (T.btroot->data)<<endl; //Old value of root is being printed
                y->ltson = z->ltson;
                y->ltson->parent = y;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: You probably need to pass variables by reference so that the value in the calling code is modified.  Remember: in the function, you're modifying a copy of the variable, not the actual variable, when you pass the variable by value.  (`void transplant(bst &T, struct node *u, struct node *v);`)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but where does the delete or free happen?

Comment: If T is the current tree, why are you passing it to the function at all? It is already accessable through the this pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you a missing a while loop or an iterator to traverse through the binary tree. This will look up for the node that needs to be deleted and then delete it regardless of its current position.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! After passing variables by reference the code seems to be working correct. But when I free "z" in delete_node method the program crashes. Could you please suggest some fix.

Comment: Now that problem is fixed, could you please tell is it good practice to use struct inside class or there is a better way to implement it?

Comment: @Neil Kirk Thanks for the advice, now I am implementing using "this" pointer.